# memory leak when use opencv-python cv2.imdecode in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: memory-leaks, opencv, python

I used Google to search for a lot of similar problems, but still not solved, sad

#### Crime scene:

##### pip:

```
grpcio==1.42.0  
grpcio-tools==1.42.0  
protobuf==3.19.1  
opencv-python==3.4.0.14  
numpy==1.19.5
```

##### system:

```
ubuntu 16.04
```

##### python version:

```
3.6.13
```

##### here is full code:

https://github.com/RiseInRose/cv2_memory_leak_ex

##### summary:

[memory_inc_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dw1Y.png)

here is i use mprof python collect data, line 39 ,mem increase ,but not release, until oom.

````
``` shell
Filename: greeter_server.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    35 1773.4336 MiB 1773.4336 MiB           1   @profile(precision=4, stream=open(f'{time.time()}.log', 'w+'))
    36                                         def jpeg_to_np(jpeg):
    37 1773.4336 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       try:
    38 1773.4336 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1           np_str = np.fromstring(jpeg, np.uint8)
    39 1775.6602 MiB   2.2266 MiB           1           image = cv2.imdecode(np_str, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    40 1775.6602 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1           del image
    41                                                 # return image
    42                                             except:
    43                                                 traceback.print_exc()
```
````

##### here is my experience:

1. In my mac. this code is not memory leak.
2. I try run code in ubuntu 18.04, is memory leak.
3. In ubuntu 16.04, is memory leak.
4. Also i use flask, run code in ubuntu 16.04, use muti threading, is memory leak.

Some one could help me? thanks!

Comment: that's a lot of code. please reduce to a [mre]. and... make sure to use the latest releases. this specific release of opencv, 3.4.0, is years old. if it's a bug, it was likely fixed years ago. nobody is going to bother investigating until you can reproduce this on latest releases.

Comment: Actually, it won’t work to replace the latest opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

Discuss this with my colleague about python GC. I tried to use python3.9 and the problem was solved.

Now i have to deal with the upgrade of all dependent libraries brought by the python upgrade. It works , that is the important!

Also, thank you, Christoph Rackwitz, you inspired me!